# MySql Count(sno) to Show old record by date

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, count

I have the following table:

[image]

```
 SELECT 
     COUNT(h.sno) AS total 
 FROM
     receipt_mov_history h,
     receipt r 
 WHERE h.rec_sno = r.sno 
    AND h.assigned_to = 6 
    AND h.is_completed = 0 
    AND h.completed_by = 0
    AND h.assigned_on <= DATE_SUB(h.assigned_on, INTERVAL 15 DAY)
ORDER BY h.sno DESC
```

I am running the above query to get all the records which having the assigned_to = 6 and older than or equal to 15 days (15 days older record). In the snapshot table you can see there is only one row which is older than 15 days (highlighted). But the above query returns 2 in result.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: the problem lies in this statement `AND h.assigned_on <= DATE_SUB(h.assigned_on, INTERVAL 15 DAY)`

Comment: Try this instead `...AND h.assigned_on <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)...`

Comment: weldone, it works like a charm. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(h.sno) AS total 
 FROM
     receipt_mov_history h,
     receipt r 
 WHERE h.rec_sno = r.sno 
    AND h.assigned_to = 6 
    AND h.is_completed = 0 
    AND h.completed_by = 0
    AND h.assigned_on <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
ORDER BY h.sno DESC
```

Comment: the issue is use have to get it from current system date

Comment: yap, you are right. is now() and curdate() working equally?

Comment: Since the `assigned_on` field is of `date` type , `NOW()` and `CURDATE()` would give you the same result in this case. @AbdulRahman

Comment: Please check this [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/66712/0) @AbdulRahman

Answer (score 2):

change `DATE_SUB(h.assigned_on, INTERVAL 15 DAY)` to `DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)`

It should be 15 days lesser than current date